# .bind not working with es6 class instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

using the `bind` documentation, if i replace the object (defined as `module` in their example), with an es6 class instance, it does not bind.

here are the docs...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

and here is my code...

```js
class Foo {}
let foo = new Foo()

let fooVar = 'foo var'
let fooFunc = () => {
  return this.var
}

foo['var'] = fooVar
fooFunc.bind(foo)
foo['func'] = fooFunc

// i expected this to return 'foo var', but instead get 'undefined'
foo.func()
```

how can i essentially add an instance method to an existing instance, and have it bind properly?

Comment: you can't bind arrow functions - also just having `fooFunc.bind(foo)` throws away the newly bound function anyway

Comment: gah! i thought arrow functions were just syntactic sugar... also, even without assigning the bound function directly, it still works. the arrow function was the only problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation about arrow function you will see that:

> Does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be used as methods.

Therefore you cant bind a new `this` if it doesnt have one

Comment: gotcha! so, this logic is part of a developer api, and if developers don't know about this rule like i didn't, is there a way i can convert their arrow function into a normal function somehow, or bind `this` to their arrow function?

Comment: @brewster you mean like this `fooFunc() {
  return this.var
}` ?

Comment: essentially yeah...  if a developer passes in an arrow function to my api, can i modify their arrow function to allow `this` to work as expected? or do i just need to be explicit in my documentation? :)